# First pattern key is always not found

Tags: java, regex

I want to read comments from .sql file and get the values:

```
<!--
@fake: some 
@author: some 
@ticket: ti-1232323 
@fix: some fix 
@release: master
@description: This is test example
-->
```

Code:

```
String text = String.join("", Files.readAllLines(file.toPath()));

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*@(?<key>(fake|author|description|fix|ticket|release)): (?<value>.*?)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find())
{
    if (matcher.group("key").equals("author")) {
        author = matcher.group("value");
    }

    if (matcher.group("key").equals("description")) {
        description = matcher.group("value");
    }    
}
```

The first key in this case `fake` is always empty. If I put `author` for the first key it's again empty. Do you know how I can fix the regex pattern?

Comment: You have no lines after you use `String text = String.join("", Files.readAllLines(file.toPath()));`. You should join with `"\n"`.

Comment: Joining with `\n` seems to work. How important are the `<!--` and `-->` ?

Comment: Very much important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
(?<!\S)@(?<key>(?:fake|author|description|fix|ticket|release)): (?<value>.*?(?![^@]))
```

The negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)` used above will match either whitespace *or* the start o the string, covering the initial edge case.  The negative lookahead `(?![^@])` at the end of the pattern will stop before the next `@` term begins, or upon hitting the end of the input

```
String text = String.join("", Files.readAllLines(file.toPath()));
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)@(?<key>(?:fake|author|description|fix|ticket|release)): (?<value>.*?(?![^@]))", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    if ("author".equals(matcher.group("key")) {
        author = matcher.group("value");
    }
    if ("description".equals(matcher.group("key")) {
        description = matcher.group("value");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Very strange. When I leave author to be the fist key it's not working.

Comment: I don't have that problem [in this demo](https://rextester.com/OBUB7019).  But admittedly, I left out the edge case of that you might not want the junk at the end of input in the final match.

Comment: Is it possible to load external file into this demo?

Comment: Not at all.  But ideally, you shouldn't need that.  Just take my code and test in your local, or come up with concise test data which covers the edge cases.

Comment: Can you try without `fake` string everywhere to reproduce the issue, please?

Comment: I have provided one valid solution to your problem.  If you don't want to use it, you may wait for other users to also answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the `<!--` and `-->` parts should be there, you could make use of the `\G` anchor to get consecutive matches and keep the groups.

Note that the alternatives are already in a named capturing group `(?<key>` so you don't have to wrap them in another group. The part in group `value` can be non greedy as you are matching to the end of the string.

As [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) mentioned, you are joining the lines back without a newline so the separate parts will not be matched using for example the anchor `$` asserting the end of the string.

*Pattern*

```
(?:^<!--(?=.*(?:\R(?!-->).*)*\R-->)|\G(?!^))\R@(?<key>fake|author|description|fix|ticket|release): (?<value>.*)$
```

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^` Start of line
  - `<!--` Match literally
  - `(?=.*(?:\R(?!-->).*)*\R-->)` Assert an ending `-->`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `\R@` Match a unicode newline sequence and `@`
- `(?<key>` Named group *key*, match any of the alternatives

  - `fake|author|description|fix|ticket|release`
- `):`  Match literally
- `(?<value>.*)$` Named group *value* Match any char except a newline until the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sMBXdQ/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/zOR6NL)

*Example code*

```
String text = String.join("\n", Files.readAllLines(file.toPath()));
String regex = "(?:^<!--(?=.*(?:\\R(?!-->).*)*\\R-->)|\\G(?!^))\\R@(?<key>fake|author|description|fix|ticket|release): (?<value>.*)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group("key").equals("author")) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group("value"));
    }

    if (matcher.group("key").equals("description")) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group("value"));
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
some 
This is test example
```